# Using streams in mysql exits out after certain count

Tags: mysql, node.js, geocoding

Below is my code, it exits after 5 iterations. I am unable to figure out why it only runs for 5 times and exits after that. I have more data in my table.

```
    function AddDataSync() {
        var query=connection.query('select officename, divisionname from table').
        stream()
        .pipe(stream.Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform: function(data,encoding,callback) {
      // do something with data...
        connection.pause();
        googleMapsClient.geocode({
               address: data.officename+' '+data.divisionname
                }, function(err, response) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(response.json.results[0].geometry.location);
            connection.resume();
            callback();
          }
          else {
            console.log(err);
            connection.resume();
          }
        });
    }
   })).on('finish',function() { console.log('done');});
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the highWaterMark in your stream. So rather than ... stream().pipe( ... you would have ... stream({highWaterMark : n}).pipe( ... where n is the maximum number of objects that can be piped. See https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#piping-results-with-streams

Comment: I did actually try that but still it doesn't work. But why would you think that is the issue?

Comment: For debugging purposes, have you tried simplifying your pipe or streaming without a pipe to see how many rows are returned by stream.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be calling `callback();` even in your else block, otherwise, the stream will be blocked.